# Scrolling header issues on a deployed report

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

So I have a report that requires scrolling row and column headers, I have checked the boxes on the tablix properties page that state **'keep header visible while scrolling'** for both row and column headers. When viewing the report, the headers behave as I would like.

The problem arises when the report is deployed and then viewed in Microsoft Edge, Internet Explore, or Chrome. The headers do not remain visible, and makes the report pretty unreadable.

I have seen previous questions that claim to answer this problem, but I have had no success. People point to deselecting the boxes I mentioned earlier, and then going to 'advanced mode' on the grouping pane, and changing `FixedData` from `False` to `True`. This doesn't seem to work, and not even in the preview of the report, which worked with the boxes checked. I am using a matrix, and not a table, and some of the 'answers' I have seen, seem to talk about only working on a table.

To be honest, there seems to be a lot of confusing comments related to this issue, and I am at a loss as to what to try next.

**Has anyone managed to find a solution to this problem, or could they point me to something that may help?**